# Solve ODE $d^2u/dx^2 + u/A = 0$

Tags: differential-equations, differentials, calculus-and-analysis

How can I solve following ODE with Mathematical:

$$d^2u/dx^2 + u/A = 0 \quad (\text{or } \  C),$$

with the conditions:

$$
\left.\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}\right|_{x=0} = 0,
$$
$$u(x=0) = B$$ and

$$\left.\frac{du}{dx}\right|_{x=W} = 0, $$

$A$, $B$, and $C$ are constants.

Comment: I think `u[x] == 0` is the only solution. Use `DSolve`,  but only use the condition `u[0] == B`. Now using the first condition conclude `B == 0`. Finally using the last condition, show `C[2] == 0`.

Comment: What *Mathematica* code have you tried?

Comment: I am new to mathematica, not sure how to write the code to do so?

Comment: Generally highest derivative should be non-zero

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your ODE $$u''(x)+\frac{1}{A} u(x) = 0$$ with constant coefficients has the characteristic polynomial $$p(\lambda)=\lambda^2 + \frac{1}{A}  \stackrel{!}{=} 0$$ with the corresponding zeros $\lambda_{1/2} = \pm \frac{i}{\sqrt{A}}$. The general (real) solution can be written as $$u(x) = U_1 \sin{\frac{x}{\sqrt{A}}} +  U_2 \cos{\frac{x}{\sqrt{A}}}$$.

Your initial condition leads to $$u(0) \stackrel{!}{=} U_2 = B$$ while the condition $$ u''(0) = -\frac{U_1}{A} \sin{\frac{x}{\sqrt{A}}} -\frac{U_2}{A} \cos{\frac{x}{\sqrt{A}}}\;\biggr|_{x=0} = -\frac{U_2}{A} \stackrel{!}{=} 0 $$
leads to $U_2=0=B$ for constant $A$. We thus have the solution

$$u(x) = U_1 \sin{\frac{x}{\sqrt{A}}}.$$

But with this solution in hand we cannot fulfill the third condition $$\lim_{x\to\infty} u(x) = 0$$ (unless U_1 = 0), since it is an oscillatory solution with a fixed amplitude (consider e.g. $x_k = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k$ for $k = 1,2,3...$.)

**Note (1):** You might get a solution for your initial value/boundary value problem if you either drop the last restriction (as suggested by Chip Hurst) or introduce a damping into your ode e.g. a term $\gamma u'(x)$.

**Note (2):** Another Method might be allowing $A$ to be negative since your solutions are then no longer oscillatory but exponential, i.e. you have

$$u(x) = U_1 e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{|A|}}} + U_2 e^{-\frac{x}{\sqrt{|A|}}}.$$

While these solutions can fulfill $$u''(0) = \frac{U_1}{|A|} e^{\frac{x}{\sqrt{|A|}}} + \frac{U_2}{|A|} e^{-\frac{x}{\sqrt{|A|}}}\;\biggr|_{x=0} = \frac{U_1}{|A|} + \frac{U_2}{|A|} \stackrel{!}{=} 0$$ for $U_1=-U_2$. They can never fulfill $\lim_{x\to\infty} u(x) = 0$ at the same time unless $u\equiv 0$, since we must have $U_1=0$ in this case which leads to $U_2=0$ via $U_1 = -U_2$.

As for mathematica code you can do all this via:

```
(* A > 0 *)  

eq = u''[x] + 1/A*u[x]
gSol[x_] = u[x] /. DSolve[eq == 0, u[x], x]
Solve[gSol[0] == b, b]
Solve[gSol''[0] == 0, {C[1], C[2]}]
(* Example Plot for U_1 = C[2] = 1 and A = 1/4 *)
Plot[gSol[x] /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 1, A -> 1/4}, {x, -2*\[Pi], 2*\[Pi]},AspectRatio->0.25]

(* A < 0 *)

eq = u''[x] - 1/A*u[x]
gSol[x_] = u[x] /. DSolve[eq == 0, u[x], x]
Solve[gSol[0] == b, b]
Solve[gSol''[0] == 0, {C[1], C[2]}]
(*Example Plot for U_1=C[2]=1 and A=1/4*)
Plot[
gSol[x] /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 1, A -> 1/4}, {x, -2*\[Pi], 2*\[Pi]}, 
AspectRatio -> 0.25]
```

Comment: Many thanks, what if A be negative, can't we get an answer like a series. The function which I mentioned above satisfy boundary conditions and its taylor expansion is very close to match the equation.

Comment: I've added the case for $A<0$ in **Note(2):**.

Comment: Generally non-trivial solutions of boundary value/ or mixed boundary initial value problems are highly dependent on your constraints (in your case they are too restrictive to admit a non-zero solution).

Comment: Thanks, What if instead of being 0 at $\infty$, the derivative at  $\infty$ be 0?

Comment: In case of the oscillatory solutions you will get no non-zero solution since the derivative is also oscillatory. An identical argument ($U_1=0$) for the first derivative holds (second derivative condition remains untouched, i.e. we still have $U_1 = -U_2$).

Comment: OK, I have changed the boundary conditions, so we don't have $\infty$ anymore.

Comment: Also please consider A is negative.

Comment: I have. Look at "Note (2):", the only thing I haven't stated there explicitly is the new ODE which is $u''-\frac{1}{|A|} u = 0$. Generally using Mathematica for your problem is overkill since it's very easy to do it by hand.